# Vending machine program java

Tags: java

In this vending machine code of mine, if I input excess funds it doesn't give me the change back. What am I missing here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Food = runMenu();
    int Price = retrievePrice(Food);
    int change = moneyInserted(Price);
}

public static int runMenu(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = 0 ;
    System.out.println("\n\nPlease enter your selection:"
                + "\n1: Snickers \t 125"
                + "\n2: Reeses Cup \t 130"
                + "\n3: Doritoes \t 150"
                + "\n4: Pepsi \t 185"
                + "\n5: Exit ");
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    return choice;        
}

public static int retrievePrice(int menuChoice){
    if (menuChoice == 1)
        return 125;
    if (menuChoice == 2)
        return 130;
    if (menuChoice == 3)
        return 150;
    if (menuChoice == 4)
        return 185;
    else return 0;
}

public static int moneyInserted(int Price){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int money = 0;
    System.out.println("Your item costs: " + Price + " Please enter the amount of money:");
    money = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (money < Price){
        System.out.println("Please insert sufficient funds");
        money = money + keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    return money - Price ;
}

public static void changeOut(int change){
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    while (change >= 25){
        quarters = quarters + 1;
        change = change - 25;
    }
    while (change >= 10){
        nickels = dimes + 1;
        change = change - 10;
        while (change >= 5){
            nickels = nickels + 1;
            change = change - 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: where are you calling changeOut? I'm not seeing it

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: Erm I'm not familiar with the quarter and pounds, but what I suggest to convert all to the lowest value first. For example in my country we have dollars and cents. So to build a vending machine that return money, I would have convert the input amount of money and the price of the food in cents. Then InputAmt - FoodPrice = ReturnMoney (all would be in cents)

Comment: You calculated the amount of change, but you didn't print it. Yes, this code is unfinished. What is preventing you from giving back change?

Comment: `nickels = dimes + 1;` means `nickels = 1;` because `dimes` isn't updated before the line.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't give me the change back"? As I see it, it *does* give the change back with `return money - Price ;`. I think what you mean is the program is not *showing* the change. If this is so, you just need to print it.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). This will increase your rep too.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does return the change, you are just not using it.

Modify your code like this:

1. After you calculate the `change`, pass it to your `changeOut()` method which is doing the change calculation in your code. To do that, add this line to the end of the `main()` method:

   ```
   changeOut(change);
   ```

2.There is slight logical mistake in your `changeOut()` method. Modify it like this:

```
public static void changeOut(int change){
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    while (change >= 25){
        quarters = quarters + 1;
        change = change - 25;
    }
    while (change >= 10){
        dimes = dimes + 1;
        change = change - 10;
    }
    while (change >= 5){
        nickels = nickels + 1;
        change = change - 5;
    }

    // to see the change, print it to the console perhaps
    System.out.printf("\nHere's your change:\n%d quarters, %d dimes, %d nickels and %d pennies!",
        quarters, dimes, nickels, change);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int totalNotes = 0;
private static int amount = 0;

private static void printAmount(int maxAmt) {
    amount = amount - maxAmt;
    totalNotes++;
    System.out.print(maxAmt + "-");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Amount");
    amount = scanner.nextInt();
    int maxAmt = 0;

    while (amount != 0) {
        if (amount >= 2000) {
            maxAmt = 2000;
        } else if (amount >= 500) {
            maxAmt = 500;
        } else if (amount >= 200) {
            maxAmt = 200;
        } else if (amount >= 100) {
            maxAmt = 100;
        } else if (amount >= 50) {
            maxAmt = 50;
        } else if (amount >= 20) {
            maxAmt = 20;
        }
        // as same you can do this for
        /*10, 5, 2, 1*/
        printAmount(maxAmt);
    }
    System.out.println("\nTotal notes : " + totalNotes);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!